# Is there any way I can know from which page I came from?

Tags: extension, gsoc

I am working on a [CiviCRM plugin that will act as a unified solution for social media login](https://github.com/siddharthg/org.civicrm.civisocial).

Once someone clicks the Login button which this plugin adds (eg to an event page), he or she is redirected to a new page for further data exchange (eg login on Twitter, Google+ etc).

Is there a way I can get to know from which the button was clicked?

One way is to store the same while clicking the button or send it to the new page as a GET or POST variable. I just wanted to check if we already storing/getting it up somewhere in CiviCRM.

Comment: What login button?

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about what you are trying to accomplish with knowing where you come from? That might help us all to provide you with options?

Comment: Sid - it might help to add documentation to the README on Github which illustrates your intended flow, as well as the features you're aiming to implement. Did we discuss that a few weeks back? Maybe it's in email or something instead of on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to a payment processor flow (especially the "button" style processors). In those, you typically pass a "return URL" to the remote site, and they would in turn direct your visitor back to the specified URL.

If the return URL needs to be a separate callback (eg an [IPN URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_payment_notification)), then you might add additional parameters (`&return=civicrm%2Fevent%3Fid%3D1%26reset%3D1`) to the IPN URL, and the IPN can in turn decode that (`civicrm/event?id=1&reset=1`) and perform a final redirect to land the user on the page they originated from.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the superglobal?  That is, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: Not reliably, browsers vary in how much referer they share, and [if a website is accessed from a HTTP Secure (HTTPS) connection and a link points to anywhere except another secure location, then the referrer field is not sent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) (I presume but haven't confirmed "link" to also mean "redirect".)